# How can I make a simple index in Latex that includes every bolded word throughout the document?

Tags: indexing

This is a very general question, but I would like to make and index for my thesis, that indexes any word that I bf in the documents, and references the page number next to it. I am using the `makeidx` package.

I just need the command to work it. Thanks guys!

Comment: When you say "any word that I bf in the documents", does that mean you're highlighting words using the ([deprecated](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41681/correct-way-to-bold-italicize-text)) `\bf` command, and you want to create an index of all occurrences of those words?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's better if you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) illustrating what you've tried.

Comment: When I say bf, I mean words like 

\textbf{nilpotent}, 

then continuing on. I just want one page at the end of the document that lists all words that have been made bold, and references the page.

I haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: Also see [Mark indexed entries in the text itself](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64249/mark-indexed-entries-in-the-text-itself).

Comment: How was this not insta-closed as a duplicate? (I am new here, but surely this has been asked and answer MANY many times)

Comment: Are you telling me that if I searched for "how do I create an index using LaTeX" I would get few results? I reckon even Bing would be useful. Anyway, here: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=creating+index+in+LaTeX @Jake

Comment: Fair enough @Jake I withdraw my comment, I am writing this only to let you know that. Sorry.

Comment: @AlecTeal: No problem!

Comment: @alecteal: I think it would be best if we both deleted our comments, since they don't help in answering the question and just add noise

Answer (score 7):

Instead of the package `hvindex`, I use this command `\dfn` in some documents:

```
%% \dfn[index entry]{defined term}
\newcommand{\dfn}[2][]{\textbf{#2}%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{\empty}}{\index{#2}}{\index{#1}}}
```

It highlights the mandatory parameter, i.e. the defined term, in bold and indexes it unless an optional parameter is provided which would take precedence. There are more advanced techniques in `makeidx`, of course, which ar enot supported by this convenient macro.

I would advise against `renewcommand`ing `\textbf`.

Answer (score 7):

As noted in [Best practice for index construction -- recommendations and references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64128/best-practice-for-index-construction-recommendations-and-references), constructing an `index` requires time, dedication, and skill, and should almost certainly *not* be automated- the results could lead to a useless `index`.

However, the following code does what you requested: it makes an `index` entry for every entry that is contained in the  `textbf` command.

Note, in particular, the [`arara`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/arara) directives at the top of the document; to compile the document (say, `myfile.tex`), simply run

```
arara myfile
```

Here's the complete code:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeindex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\let\oldtextbf\textbf
\renewcommand{\textbf}[1]{%
\oldtextbf{#1}%
\index{#1}
}
\makeindex
\begin{document}

\textbf{my text}

\clearpage
\textbf{another}
\printindex
\end{document}
```